# Joining SQL tables and removing repetitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a list of the customers with the same phone number, as there are instances of the same customer being created two or three times with slightly different names.

The query below has almost the intended behavior:

```
SELECT C1.CUSTOMER_NAME, C2.CUSTOMER_NAME, C1.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM CUSTOMER C1 
JOIN CUSTOMER C2
ON C1.PHONE_NUMBER = C2.PHONE_NUMBER
WHERE C1.CUSTOMER_NAME != C2.CUSTOMER_NAME
AND C1.PHONE_NUMBER != ''
ORDER BY C1.CUSTOMER_NAME
```

But I get repetions like:

```
Customer A - Customer B
Customer A - Customer C
Customer B - Customer A
Customer B - Customer C
Customer C - Customer A
Customer C - Customer B
```

When all I want to get is the first two lines, which are enough to cover all the cases.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Clear what u want its bit confusing write desired result and provide ur resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you want just the first two lines . . . because the last line seems different.

In any case, you can replace the `!=` with `<` to get what you want:

```
SELECT C1.CUSTOMER_NAME, C2.CUSTOMER_NAME, C1.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM CUSTOMER C1 JOIN
     CUSTOMER C2
     ON C1.PHONE_NUMBER = C2.PHONE_NUMBER AND
        C1.CUSTOMER_NAME < C2.CUSTOMER_NAME
WHERE C1.PHONE_NUMBER <> ''
ORDER BY C1.CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

If you just want all the customers on a given phone number -- when there is more than one customer -- then you do not need a `join`:

```
select c.phone_number, c.name
from (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by phone_number) as cnt
      from customer c
     ) c
where cnt > 1
order by c.phone_number, c.name;
```

Comment: You are correct that the last case is different, but when they update the phone numbers of A, B and C, that last case will also be fixed. I like the best solution better, just because it's closer to what I was expecting, but the second one also works correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery (or JOIN with same login) to get the duplicate numbers first, then report on all the customers with that number:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE PHONE_NUMBER IN (SELECT PHONE_NUMBER
                       FROM CUSTOMER
                       WHERE COUNT(PHONE_NUMBER) > 1 AND PHONE_NUMBER != '')
ORDER BY PHONE_NUMBER
```